# scp from remote to local, username has '@' character

Tags: ssh, scp

I have exported a db file from our staging server and need to secure copy the file from the remote server to my local machine. The issue that I am having, my username has a '@' character in it.

When I login via ssh I have to use a slightly weird syntax because of this:

```
ssh -o User=username@companyname 192.xxx.xxx.xx
```

Everything I try is resulting in a syntax error.

What I have tried:

```
scp 'username@companyname'192.xxx.xx.xx:/file/to/send /where/to/put

scp -o User=username@remote 192.xxx.xxx.xx:/file/to/send /where/to/put
```

Not really sure what else to try and don't want to spend too much time shooting in the dark.

At this point I could just use Filezilla and grab the file via sftp, but i'd like to know how to do this.

Thanks for any solid input with this.

Comment: What kind of server is that where you have usernames with `@` in them? That sounds like a really bad idea. I'd look for a way to change it, or add an alias (at the sshd level if not at the OS level)

Comment: Changing it is not an option, I have no control. And to be honest, I'm not 100% sure what kind of server it is... We run nginx for all our development sites

Comment: `scp -o User=username@remote ...` ought to work. What specifically happens when you try that form? What actual error message are you getting?

Comment: I found that `scp user@foo@bar:baz .` seems to connect to `bar` and send `user@foo` as the username, in a recent version of openssh.

Comment: @Kenster you are correct. I actually closed my terminal so I'm not sure the exact command and error I was getting, but I tried again using `scp -o User=username@companyname 192.168.xxx.xxx:dumpfile.sql path/to/put/file`

Comment: Putting the user in the ``.ssh/config`` file would also be a solution, rather than the more verbose ``-o User=...`` option